# Rearranging a vector in parallel for fast performance

Tags: vector, parallel-processing, fortran, fortran90

I have a vector whose length can go up to about a few million or more.

If I say the vector is `vec = [a1 a2 ...b1 b2 ... c1 c2 ...d1 d2 ...]`

I need to rearrange `vec` to `new_vec = [a1 b1 c1 d1 a2 b2 c2 d2 ...]` .

If viewed as a matrix of column vectors, then this could be viewed as a transpose, but I do not have a two dimensional vector. I understand how to do it on a sequential computer. That is very simple.

But I am not sure how to do this on a multiple processor cluster or on a GPU, or even if this would be feasible on parallel machines. Memory seems to be the obvious bottleneck. If there are any algorithms or any architecture specific optimizations that I can use, please let me know.

Edit: More information below.

The code structure is:

```
subroutine reorder(vec,parameter)

real(kind = 8),dimension(parameter%length), intent(inout) :: vec
real(kind = 8),dimension(parameter%length) :: temp
type(param)                                :: parameter !just a struct holding certain constant parameters
integer                                    :: i,j,k,q1,q2,q3,nn1,n1,n2,nn2

i1 = parameter%len1    !lengths of sub-vectors in each direction 
i2 = parameter%len2    !the multiplication of the 3 gives the 
                       !overall length of vec
i3 = parameter%len3

temp = vec

n1 = i2*i1
n2 = i2*i3
   do k = 1, i3
      q1 = n1*(k-1)
      q2 = i2*(k-1)
      do j = 1, i2
         q3 = i1*(j-1)
         do i = 1, i1
            nn1 = q1+q3+i
            nn2 = q2+j+n2*(i-1)
            vec(nn2) = temp(nn1)
         end do
      end do
   end do

end subroutine reorder
```

Therefore the code aims to reorder the elements of the vector according to the rule. As you can see as the length of the vector becomes very large, a significant time is spent in this routine.

This routine is called in a main routine multiple times. A cartesian decomposition produces a cartesian 3D arrangement of ranks in the beginning and each rank calls this subroutine when a reordering of the elements is required for its own next subroutine call.The cartesian communicator subroutine is shown in the skeleton below:

```
subroutine cartesian_comm(ndim,comm_cart,comm_one_d,coord_cart)
use mpi
implicit none
integer, dimension(:), intent(in)  :: ndim
integer,               intent(out) :: comm_cart
integer, dimension(:), pointer     :: comm_one_d, coord_cart
logical, dimension(size(ndim))     :: period, remain
integer :: dim,code, i, rank

!creating the cartesian communicator
dim = 3
allocate(comm_one_d(dim),coord_cart(dim))
period   = .FALSE.
call MPI_CART_CREATE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, dim, ndim, period, .FALSE., comm_cart, code)
call MPI_COMM_RANK(comm_cart, rank, code)
call MPI_CART_COORDS(comm_cart, rank, dim, coord_cart, code)

!Creating sub-communicator for each direction
do i = 1, dim
   remain = .FALSE.
   remain(i) = .TRUE.
   call MPI_CART_SUB(comm_cart, remain, comm_one_d(i), code)
end do
end subroutine cartesian_comm
```

And it is called in the main function as follows:

```
Program main
!initialize some stuff and intialize all the required variables

! ndim is the number of processes the program is called 
! with "mpirun -np 8 ./exec" would mean ndim is cuberoot of 8,
! and therefore 2 for the 3D case. It is always made sure that
! np is a cube(or square for 2D) while calling the program

call cartesian_comm(ndim,comm_cart,comm_one_d,coord_cart)

  do while (t<tend-1D-8)  !start time loop
    t = t + dt
    !do some computations get the vector "vec" for 
    !each rank separately (different and independent in each rank)

    call reorder(vec,parameter) ! all ranks call this subroutine

    !do some computations here with the new reordered vec

  end do !end time loop

!do other stuff (unrelated to reorder but use the "vec" vector) here

end Program main
```

I would like to know if there is a better way to do this in a multiprocessor cluster, or how I could proceed in the case of a GPU.

Comment: This looks pretty broad to me. Using a cluster and using accelerators (GPU) are completely independent. You can do both at the same time or just one. And everything will change if your vector is distributed over several nodes of the cluster. You really need to tell as at least whether it is distributed or not and if yes how exactly. It changes everything.

Comment: *I need to rearrange ...* Really ?  You **need** to ?  Sometimes such needs go away with a little further thought.  Perhaps you **need** to stride through it with non-unit step length ?  If you explain why you ask the question you might get answers to the question you should have asked.  Or not.

Comment: I compute the elements of the vector on multiple processors and then collect them on the main processor. Therefore the vector is not distributed among processors, but present only on the main processor. After I rearrange, I send them again to all the processors. And after some computations, this process repeats iteratively. As the vector is large, this constant exchange is proving to be very inefficient. Non-unit stride is not an option because then I don't have continuous memory access, and that will also be inefficient.

Comment: I think you have to describe exactly what you are doing in your question. Edit it! Show some code!  You should thing how to avoid all that collecting on one processor. Think about things like MPI_AllToAll(). Are you using MPI or what are you actually using? Be specific!

Comment: There is the RESHAPE in F90... have you considered that?

Comment: You didn't show much. You should show the parallel part, the Cartesian decomposition... It is still very unclear.

Comment: I think we are seriously misunderstanding each other. I think I am not the only one, because no-one was able to answer your question. You show how to create a Cartesian communicator, but you don't have to show THAT. You should show how you distribute your data in the Cartesian grid of processes. How do you collect the data to the master. That is the important part. I still don't know which part of the data has which process and why is any reordering necessary. It may seem I am bitching all the time but I am trying to guide you to make a question that someone can answer.

Comment: I am happy to edit and explain the question as much as asked, as it helps me understand and come up with ideas as well. I am sorry about the misunderstanding which may be caused by my previous comment (I explained it wrong there). The vector "vec" is local to each processor and the reordering is done in each of the processors and not like as I have written in my previous comment. So. please disregard my previous comment.